# Python script and batch file run fine manually, but not when scheduled

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I am using Windows 10 Pro. I have made my example as simple as possible. The code just writes some logs in a log file.

This is my python script: `C:\Users\myname.mysurname\Downloads\test.py`

```
import os
import logging


def main():
    logger.info('hi')
    try:
        logger.info('bye')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.debug(e)
        return 1
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Gets or creates a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    # set log level
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # define file handler and set formatter
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logfile.log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add file handler to logger
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    exit(main())
```

This is my batch file: `C:\Users\myname.mysurname\Downloads\batch_file.bat`

```
C:\Users\myname.mysurname\Python\Envs\default\Scripts\Activate.bat && python C:\Users\myname.mysurname\Downloads\test.py pause
```

I confirm:

- the python script runs fine when executed in PyCharm.
- the batch file runs fine when I double-click on it.
- All the files are saved locally.
- I'm logged on.
- I have admin rights in my PC.

This is my Windows Scheduler setup:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I haven't even created a trigger yet, as I'm testing the setup. When I manually click on "Run" in Windows Scheduler, the status changes from "Ready" to "Running" and a black command window pops up and disappears immediately (so I cannot read what it says). Nothing happens next. The status remains "Running" forever until I eventually manually stop it. When I check history, I see it starts and ends simultaneously. Then I check the logfile.log and see that it's not been modified, but I'd expect to see something like this:

[image]

What is the problem? Otherwise, how can I debug?

Comment: add "PAUSE" to the end of bat file so the command prompt window will stay open then check what is going on.

Comment: Try to use an absolute path to the log file because relative paths may not point to the expected location.

Comment: @OmidShojaee I added pause at the end of my batch file but it's not pausing when I run with the Windows scheduler or manually double-clicking on the .bat file. I edited the question so that you can see how I added pause at the end. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Your batch file should be ```@Call "%UserProfile%\Python\Envs\default\Scripts\Activate.bat" && "P:\athTo\python.exe" "%UserProfile%\Downloads\test.py"```. When you run a batch file from another and wish to return to it, and do something else in the same environment, you need the `CALL` command.

Answer (score 0):

Using an absolute path to the log file instead of a relative path solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).